# Unexpected double value output when using printf

Tags: c, function, integer, signed

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double  a=7.1;
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1717986918
```

When I am writing this program and using signed format specifiers to the method `printf()`. Why I am getting this value?

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to print a `double` value with the conversion specifier `"%d"`. Anything could happen. Your program could crash, for example... or format your hard drive ... or nasal daemons might come out your nose (another option is your program interprets the bit sequence for the double value `7.1` as the bit sequence for the integer `1717986918` ignoring any left over bits if any)

Comment: So the `%f` or `%lf` specifier is what you need.

Comment: Using compiler warning flags is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Its a [format specifier](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c) problem.
Using `"%d"`, the compiler is being told that the type of data being printed is of type `int`, but the variable is of type `float`, causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), resulting in this case, the value `1717986918`.

The format specifier for type `float` is `"%f"`, not `"%d"`.

Change this:

```
printf("%d",a);
```

To this:

```
printf("%f",a);
```

If you compile with `-Wall` or equivalent in your compiler settings, a warning for this will notify you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior. It's not defined what should be the output of your code and as far as any programmer should be concerned, your code [spawns nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

> **why** I am getting this output in my Cprogram?

I am *assuming* lot about your computer and compiler implementation, such as that your compiler uses IEEE754 standard to represent floating point numbers and the size of an `int` is 4 bytes and that your computer uses little endian. According to [this site](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=055046049) the double number `7.1` when represented as a IEEE754 double precision number is stored as 8 bytes as a `0x401C666666666666` number. Then those bytes are passed to `printf` as variadic arguments. Because of how on your architecture arguments are passed, the least significant 4 bytes from that number are extracted for `printf` `%d` format specifier, which results in printing the base 10 representation of `0x66666666` number, which is `1717986918`.